# Is there a way to store/retrieve arbitrary data structures on Microsoft Azure? (Windows Phone7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to be able to store an arbitrary C# struct with some variables on the Azure SQL server and retrieve it later into a similar struct. How can I do this without knowing the structure of the database?

Comment: I suggest you edit your "question" and turn it into an actual question. As it stands, you haven't really provided any context to what you're trying to accomplish. It's unclear what you mean by "on the Azure server," as there is no single Azure server. Are you talking about a Compute instance? Windows Azure Table Storage? Blob Storage? SQL Azure?

Comment: Sorry the question wasnt very clear, I've edited it to make it a little more clear.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Azure is very similar to SQL Server, as you would build your schema, tables, rows, etc. the same way. If you wanted a schemaless approach to data types, you'd need to serialize your objects to some generic column, along with a Type column. Or use a Property table approach.

Alternatively, Windows Azure has a schema-free storage construct, the Windows Azure Table. Each row may contain different data. You'd just need some mechanism for determining the type of data you wrote (maybe one of the row properties, perhaps). Azure Tables are lightweight compared to SQL Azure, in that it's not a relational database. Each row is referenced by a Partition Key and Row Key (the pair being essentially a composite key).

So... assuming you don't have complex search / index requirements, you should be able to use Azure Tables to accomplish what you're trying to do.

[This blog post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309178.aspx) goes over the basics of both SQL Azure and Azure Tables.

There are also examples of using Azure Tables in the [Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8396).